# Switching the MKMapView display language

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to switch the underlying language of MKMapView to a different one than the system locale?

For example, if the address displays translated street names (English) but I need to see the native language translations (e.g. in mainland China or Japan).

A alternative to this is to include a local Map Engine (like Baidu) but I wish to see if iOS can do that out of the box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map will display in the language of the country it is displaying, often with English (or maybe your local language) as a second language. Open the Maps app on your phone and type in Dubai or Cairo, Egypt, for example, and you'll see Arabic text for cities and streets.

The same is true of other languages. Type Shanghai, China and you'll get Chinese text, Tokyo, Japan and you'll get Japanese text, etc.

There is (as of now) no open framework functions to manually change the languages of the input. I know that the openstreetmap API have some calls for this, but that would require rolling your own map handler.

Comment: Thanks, nothing we can do about it at this stage except adding OSM for such feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use `googlesdk` for this. I do it, its too useful according to local location the map will convert into local language and if you worry about the annotation and multiple annotation you can implement all those things just like `MKMapview`

Comment: And, I can change the language of the map with an API call? What is it? (I do not want to change the phone language for this).

Answer (score 2):

The Maps application has an option for showing labels in the local language instead of the system language, but this option isn’t available to MapKit.

The [Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/) does have an option for localizing labels into either the local language in each region or to one of nine languages globally (based on OpenStreetMap and Wikidata).

To change all the labels on the map to the system language, have your `MGLMapViewDelegate` object implement the `-mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:` method, then call the `-[MGLStyle localizeLabelsIntoLocale:]` method.

In Swift:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
    // Into the system language
    style.localizeLabels(into: nil)
    // Into Simplified Chinese
    style.localizeLabels(into: Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans"))
    // Into the local language where a given feature is located
    style.localizeLabels(into: Locale(identifier: "mul"))
}
```

Or in Objective-C:

```
- (void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didFinishLoadingStyle:(MGLStyle *)style {
    // Into the system language
    [style localizeLabelsIntoLocale:nil];
    // Into Simplified Chinese
    [style localizeLabelsIntoLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh-Hans"]];
    // Into the local language where a given feature is located
    [style localizeLabelsIntoLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"mul"]];
}
```

There are also options for localizing certain kinds of features, such as only streets or only landmarks. See [this document](https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/#mapbox-maps-sdk-for-ios) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

By **forcing the app default language** one can overcome this constraint. Though pricey, it does pay off.

> ```
> let langCultureCode: String = "en"
> let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
> defaults.set([langCultureCode], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
> defaults.synchronize() 
> // UserDefaults.standard.set(["AR"], forKey: "AppleLanguages") // case Arabic
> ```

In my application users with **Arabic based devices** were erroneously searching out of my database with their Arabic country and city names.

**regionDidChangeAnimated?**

```
    // الرياض, السعودية
    // دبي ، الإمارات
    // القاهرة، مصر
```

**Forcibly ignoring the device default language** does not come freely.  Restoring back my Mapview functionality, made my app abandon any localized string. And there were plenty.

[image]

**regionDidChangeAnimated?**

```
// Riyadh, Saudi Arabia 
// Dubai , United Arab Emirates
// Cairo , Egypt
```

- Odd thing the mapView ignores my app default language setup and renders labels with user default language. Which happens to be an accidental advantage

Comment: @iKT did you set this up inside your AppDelegate.swift class?

Comment: I have added UserDefaults code in my LocalizeManager class. And this LocalizeManager changing language after loggedin.

Comment: @iKT what language are you trying to force in your App? I am targeting Arabic, so `UserDefaults.standard.set(["AR"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")` works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `style.localizeLabels(into: Locale.current)` in your `mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle)` function.

Make sure that your app has enabled that certain language in the project settings and that MapBox supports that language.