# change the MKMapView display language in application

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Is it possible to switch the underlying language of MKMapView according to select language in our application?
when user select english then the language of map should be in english and when user select arabic language then language of map should be in arabic language.

without any change is setting of map.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040167/switching-the-mkmapview-display-language This question thread should answer your question. If it does, delete this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `googlesdk` for this... i do it its too usefull according to local location the map will convert into.. local language ...and if you worry about the annotation and multiple annotation ...  u can implement all that thinks just like `MKMapview`